# How to get all child records by Parent from a single MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I have a MySQL table with parent child relationship. I need to update one field of all child records when I give the parent id. Parent can have unlimited  child levels in the table.

My table is like this

ID    Name     ParentID

1     a

2     b        1

3     c        2

4     d        1

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Child where parent_id in(select parent_id from Parent)
```

Above example should work for you, also always mention what you have tried in the question.

**better solution** *Create different table like Parent, Child, grand Child. Parent Id should be present in Child table and Child_id should be there in Grand Child table.* This will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But this is not working for me. All my records are in one table. with ParentID column in it.

Comment: So, parent entries(Parent_id) are repeating in your table for each child ?

Comment: yes.. my table is like this

Comment: ok.. np.. select * from table where parent_id = 4 is not working ? Can you share the query you are trying.

Comment: I need all child records to be listed... for example if I say parent id 1 I need all 2,3,4 listed.. 3 need also need to be listed as 1 is grand parent of 3. like this I have unlimited level of child records

Comment: ID Name ParentID

1 a 0

2 b 1

3 c 2

4 d 1 if you say parent_id=1 you will get only entries 2 & 4. You should query on what is common there.

Comment: **better solution** _Create different table like Parent, Child, grand Child. Parent Id should be present in Child table and Child_id should be there in Grand Child table_ This will solve your problem.